# Is it possible to link create an ID tag for a link element?

Tags: html

So I'm writing HTML, one of my first exercises it's me remaking a wiki page, and as wiki pages do, they have a lot of text. And so it gets too "spammed"? in the text editor.
I have a lot of links I need to connect to many paragraphs, and that even makes it worse to see.

My question is, is it possible to create a "variable" or something like it elsewhere with the URL information and tag it with an ID, so that in the paragraph i call that link with the ID, so ppl can click it, and so the paragraph doesn't look so long for my eyes
like:

variable id"2": google.com

<pThis is a <link id=2 Link </link to google</p

You can tell I'm super new to programming HTML so, just let me know if that's possible, and excuse my bad HTML! XD

Apparently  doesn't make a link to another page, so I'm confused about that as well, didn't expect this.

Comment: The anchor tag `<a href="...">content</a>` tag is used to create links to other pages. I'm not really following the rest of your question, but hopefully that helps. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML anchor tag to add links
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

```html
   <p>This is a <a id="2" href="https://www.google.com/"> Link </a> to google</p>
```

**Update**

> I want the actual link information to be elsewhere in the code, not in the actual paragraph!

What I understand from this comment is you want to link some word or sentence to some information which is not there in the current paragraph using id.

To achieve this, instead of adding URL to the `href` of `<a>` you can add the variable id of that element (in your case it's paragraph).

So now when you click on that it will take you to the element with that id.

Example

```css
.block {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#1">Go to paragraph 1</a><br>
  <a href="#2">Go to paragraph 2</a><br>
  <a href="#3">Go to paragraph 3</a><br>
  <a href="#6">Go to paragraph 6</a><br>
</p>
<div class="block" id="1">Block/paragraph 1</div>
<div class="block" id="2">Block/paragraph 2</div>
<div class="block" id="3">Block/paragraph 3</div>
<div class="block" id="4">Block/paragraph 4</div>
<div class="block" id="5">Block/paragraph 5</div>
<div class="block" id="6">Block/paragraph 6</div>
```

Another use case

If the information to which you want to redirect the user is on another page, and that information also have an id attribute added to it, then mention the id with that page.

```
<a href="page2.html#id"><a/>
```

Comment: Please share more details. How does this use the concept of a "variable" that Joao is searching for?

Comment: Thanks for trying @Mohit_Kushawaha. I know I'm quite unclear, mostly due to lack of experience, hence the hardship in trying to ask for help!
But the answer you provided is not what I was looking for, you see, I want the actual link information to be elsewhere in the code, not in the actual paragraph!
I'll edit my question to make it more clear!

Comment: @Joao_Garcao please check the updated answer, I've updated it after understanding your comment.
please let me know if any issue is still there.

Comment: "Your requirement is to link some word or sentence to some other paragraph" - how did you guess that? As far as I read the requirement, the source code of the page should contain any kind of "variable" that is expanded on rendering the page

Comment: @NicoHaase please read the recent comment, he mentioned that "I want the actual link information to be elsewhere in the code, not in the actual paragraph!". It only means that he want to link the word to some information which is elsewhere but not in the actual paragraph.